# Cannot add actions to custom buttons on word "Text" popup menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word, contextmenu

I've been having a real tough time the following.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Beta, developing a word template (.dotm) in Visual Basic.Net

I'm trying to add my own buttons on the text popup/context menu of word.  However if I use the .OnAction property, I get an error msg in word stating the following:

The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your macro security settings

I'm assuming I get this error because it cannot locate the sub I'm trying to call (the name is correct and it resides in the same class).

I tried a different approach which is the WithEvents, however that associates the event with the LAST button I add to the menubar.

A third approach I tried was the AddHandler, that one fires once on then no more.

Here is the code I use:

```
For Each myItem In activeDoc.CommandBars
        If myItem.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoBarType.msoBarTypePopup And myItem.Name = officeMenuName Then
            shortMenu = Me.activeDoc.CommandBars(myItem.Index).Controls
            shortPopup = shortMenu.Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, Temporary:=True)

            With shortPopup
                .Caption = menuName
                .Visible = True
            End With

            For i = LBound(menuItems) To UBound(menuItems)

                shortItem = shortPopup.Controls.Add(Type:=Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
                AddHandler shortItem.Click, AddressOf shortMenuNu

                With shortItem
                    .Caption = menuHeader(i)
                    .Visible = True
                    .Tag = menuItems(i)

                    .OnAction = "shortMenuItem_Click" 'where the name of the sub resides in the same class
                    'or AddHandler shortItem.Click, AddressOf shortMenuItem_Click
                End With

                shortItem = Nothing
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

I would appreciate any input on this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same symptoms. In my case, I had an `OnAction` defined for the `CommandBar` control containing the `ComandBarPopup` control. There is no action on the containing control.